# How can I transfer my Metamask account to Trezor?

Tags: metamask, trezor

I have an account on MetaMask. I'd like to know if I load the account into Trezor without having to send the funds from the MetaMask account to the Trezor account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the Trezor and any hardware wallet is to generate a seed/private key offline.  The device itself generates the seed/private key.  See here: [Trezor seed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54610/how-does-trezors-wallet-recovery-work-if-the-private-key-never-leaves-the-devic)

Therefore, it is not possible to move your Metamask address to your Trezor since you can not manually override or create private keys on the hardware wallet.

In any event, doing so would defeat the purpose of the hardware wallet.  Since the Metamask private key is generated and stored on your computer, the security vulnerability is that your computer which is online can potentially be hacked, in which case such a hacker would potentially have access to your Metamask private keys.

Hardware wallets are designed to eliminate this risk.

Comment: just a note on hw wallets. it could be reasonably useful to import a metamask seed/key, in order to allow wallet/account use on potentially compromised systems (eg. school or public library). https://digitalbitbox.com/ethereum supports this